# How to update shard key of mongodb collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

There is a requirement to update a value of one field of all the documents. Unfortunately this field is shard key for that collection. For example documents inside the collection is as follows,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c0763afaabfc3000eb44cc0ss"),
    "sensorId" : "someid",
    "liftId" : "some-lift-id", //Shared key
    "startTimestamp" : NumberLong(1543988140912),
    "endTimestamp" : NumberLong(0),
    "value" : {}
}
```

I want to update value of `liftId` to new value ( new value >> `prefix-some-lift-id`) in all the documents.

This is what I've tried,

```
db.getCollection('lift_events').find({}).forEach(
    function (elem) {
        db.getCollection('lift_events').update(
            {
                _id: elem._id
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    liftId: 'prefix-' + elem.liftId 
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

But this fails, because `liftId` is the shard key for the collection. Is there any way to achieve this for all the shards without specifying the shard key?

`db.version() : 3.4.6` and this is a Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB

Comment: In MongoDB, [shard key field and values are immutable](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/limits/#Shard-Key-is-Immutable). This means a shard key field cannot be changed, and, the shard key value for each document cannot be changed. I don't know about this behavior for _Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB_; please refer the appropriate documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing a Shard Key is possible only

- if you are using MongoDB version 4.2
- Sharding key is not the unique key `_id` of the document

> To change the Shard Key you need to follow the below steps

There is no automatic support in MongoDB for choosing a different shard key after sharding a collection. This reality underscores the importance of choosing a good shard key. If you must change a shard key after sharding a collection, the best option is to:

- Dump all data from MongoDB into an external format.
- Drop the original sharded collection.
- Configure sharding using a more ideal shard key.
- Pre-split the shard key range to ensure initial even distribution.
- Restore the dumped data into MongoDB.

In this case `"liftId" : "some-lift-id"` is not the unique key `_id` and if you are using MongoDB version 4.2 then you can change your sharded key by following the steps given above

But it is a good practice always to choose a good Sharding Key seperated with underscores before doing the sharding.

References

[Shard Keys](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-shard-key/)

[Sharding FAQ's](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/sharding/)